# Ratio of Column Based on Date

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding SQL.

Say I have the following table:

```
customerID | time_secs | date
-----------+-----------+-----------
1          | 5         | 01/09/2020
1          | 4         | 01/09/2020
1          | 2         | 01/10/2020
2          | 1         | 01/11/2020
2          | 3         | 01/11/2020
3          | 6         | 01/12/2020
3          | 8         | 01/12/2020
```

I can't change the table design. I want to be able to calculate for each unique customer, the percent of time_secs that is over 3, but for each date.

So for example, for customer 1, on 01/09, it would be (4 + 5) / 2 * 100%. For customer 1, on 01/10, it would be 0%.

I've gotten this so far:

```
select customers,
   avg(case when time_seconds > 3 then 100.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from t
group by customerid;
```

However, this does the total based on all dates. How do I divvy it up into separate dates as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when time_seconds > 3 then 1.0 else 0 end) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by customerid)
from t;
```

You can multiply by 100 if you want a value between 0 and 100 rather than 0 and 1.

Comment: Don't have access to those functions.

Comment: @legit98 . . . To what functions?  They are standard SQL and pretty much in all supported versions of almost every database.